# Android Spinner: Custom Adapter Display

Tags: android, spinner, simplecursoradapter

I am using a SimpleCursorAdapter on my spinner because I want to create a custom dropDownList that contains multiple rows and populate it from my database. I have accomplished this task quite nicely, but on my layout activity, the spinner shows the selected rows and I would like it to have a separate layout so it shows only the first line of the selected row. How can I accomplish this?

```
String fields[] = {"name", "lovibond", "gravity"};
    nameAdapter = new GrainSpinnerAdapter(this, R.layout.grain_spinner_row, data, fields, new int[] { R.id.GrainSpinnerName, R.id.GrainSpinnerLovibond, R.id.GrainSpinnerGravity });
    nameSpinner.setAdapter(nameAdapter);
```

Here is my SimpleCursorAdapter code:

```
public class GrainSpinnerAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

    private Context myContext;

    public GrainSpinnerAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to) {
        super(context, layout, c, from, to);
        myContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
        super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

        int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        String getName = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerName);
        name.setText(getName);

    }

    @Override
    public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grain_spinner, null);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public View newDropDownView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
        super.newDropDownView(context, cursor, parent);

        View view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.grain_spinner_row, null);
        int nameColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("name");
        String getName = cursor.getString(nameColumn);
        TextView name = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerName);
        name.setText(getName);

        int loviColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("lovibond");
        String getLovi = cursor.getString(loviColumn);
        TextView lovi = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerLovibond);
        lovi.setText(getLovi);

        int gravityColumn = cursor.getColumnIndex("gravity");
        String getGravity = cursor.getString(gravityColumn);
        TextView gravity = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.GrainSpinnerGravity);
        gravity.setText(getGravity);

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Completely on a side-topic, is this app for homebrewing?  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are asking is the `getDropDownView()` method of [**BaseAdapter**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html) class.

In your newView method do what you've done and provide a layout for single row displays.

Then implement newDropDownView to inflate another layout that provides for multiple lines.
The drop down views are used to create rows in the popup menu that is provided when a user selects the dropdown.

Comment: I updated my question to include the newly implemented newDropDownView, but its throwing an error. I actually have tried this once before with no luck. I'm probably missing something really simple...

Comment: Figured it out and updated my question. I needed to bind my objects in the newDropDownView and use a custom layout in the newView while binding its object in the bindView.