# Spinner and add imageview elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a little problem. I create a spinner in code using: `spinner = new Spinner(getApplicationContext());`, but I don't know how I can add items to this spinner, but this items should be images view, without text. Do you know any tutorial to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to implement custom adapter for your spinner and custom view for one item.

You can look at this [Android Spinner: Custom Adapter Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6835032/android-spinner-custom-adapter-display)